# Is there a theory that trying to solve intuition and fear at the same time?

Tags: epistemology, phenomenology, emotions, intuition, cognitive-psychology

I'm looking for a school of thought or theory that solves these problems, preferably at once:

1. The way to make a profound, advanced knowledge more straightforward and imaginative, without having to oversimplify it. For example if Kant considered

   > The starry heavens above me and the moral law within me

   is straightforward, then shouldn't his book have begun with this?
2. The dissatisfaction on interpersonal issues, whereas we keep misunderstood each other, and frustrated for don't know how to seek for the balance point to get to the maturity. Many advice contradict each other and are easier said than done (be simple vs do the right thing, be flexible vs be discipline, etc).

In other words, the theory itself must be:

1. intuitive enough to explain to a kid (epistemology)
2. helpful for an adult to overcome their fears by themselves (phenomenology)

I'm not sure whether (1) has been discussed before, and I guess (2) requires an understanding in information theory, phil of mind or phil of language, because "the limit of my language is the limit of my world". (2) is also about emotional self-regulation and communication/interpersonal skills in psychology.

Comment: I think what you are asking for may be a bit too custom tailored to a particular need.  In my own explorations of philosophy, I have found *every* school of thought answers those questions in their own way, but that doesn't always mean they are useful to each and every individual.  However, a common thread I find between them may be helpful.  Most theories which are taught to kids do not come in one big slug as "a theory."  They are something which is built up, layer after layer, as the individual is ready to progress further.

Comment: As an example, I would not teach my own views on murder as a theory to a child.  However, some fundamental seeds could be taught to a five year old, and they can grow with the child.  Indeed some of the seeds of what violence *is* are things I strive to help my toddler understand within her own faculties.  They all build on eachother and mature over time.

Comment: You do not specify the age of the child, but if the child is old enough, I have found the concept of the elephant rider to be useful.  It's the idea that we have an "emotional" mind which is the elephant, and a "thinking" mind which is the rider.  Arguably the rider is in control, but in practice we find its a much more complex system.  I find it proves to be a useful model because at it's simplest, a two part system, it describe a lot of really useful things, but as you mature it, you start to have to question whether the idea of "who is in control" is even a meaningful question.

Comment: If you care to discuss it further, we can open up a [chat] room, where we can go into particulars which one tries to avoid when writing good SE questions.

Comment: @CortAmmon https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81383/theories-that-trying-to-solve-intuition-and-fear-at-the-same-time. Thanks for your help